# Failed to load session 'unity 2-d'

Tags: 12.04, unity-2d, medibuntu

When logging in Ubuntu 12.04 it says "Failed to load session 'unity 2-d'" and there is only an option to log out...

Now the problem occurred when I was fixing a simple medibuntu problem, after some exploring I came down to simply removing the leftover medibuntu repositories...

but, unfortunately I also followed the instructions from this answer  [How to remove medibuntu repository and packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223179/how-to-remove-medibuntu-repository-and-packages), mainly I ran this code suggested in the answer:

```
PKGS=$(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep -e aacgain -e aacplusenc -e acroread-fonts -e alsa-firmware -e app-install-data-medibuntu -e apport-hooks-medibuntu -e hot-babe -e ices -e libavcodec-extra-53 -e libavdevice-extra-53 -e libav-extra-dbg -e libavfilter-extra-2 -e libavformat-extra-53 -e libavutil-extra-51 -e libdvdcss2 -e libdvdcss-dev -e libpostproc-extra-52 -e libswscale-extra-2 -e medibuntu-keyring -e mencoder -e mplayer-dbg -e mplayer-doc -e mplayer-gui -e mplayer -e non-free-codecs -e rmconverter -e w32codecs -e w64codecs | tr '\n' ' '); sudo apt-get purge $PKGS
```

after that, the computer was switched off, and got the before mentioned error next time it turned on. Also, there is **no** other session available to choose from! Only the back button...

Can all of the removed software be re-installed?

How can I repair this?

Comment: Can you not use 3D?

Comment: No as I said, there is no other session to choose from

Comment: But 12.04 comes with just plain unity as well as 2d

Comment: After i ran the command mentioned above there are no sessions to choose from ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be reinstalled, however, you were originally trying to get rid of that software so lets not fix this problem by settling for a problem that's not as bad. Here's how to fix the problem by installing the desktop of your choice so you can enjoy your operating system once again.

First, power up your computer and when everything seems to be booted up, press CTRL + ALT + F2 . Doing this will take you to a login screen in a text only session with no desktop. Enter your username and then your password to sign in.

After you sign in, type the following command to update your package list before installing any packages.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now, If you want the standard Ubuntu desktop with the Standard Unity interface, type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

To install Gnome-Shell instead of Unity, type:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome gnome-shell
```

To install the Xubuntu desktop type:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

To install Ubuntustudio, type:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-desktop
```

For the Lubuntu desktop, type:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

& for Kubuntu, type:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

when your desired desktop is installed type this command to reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't intend to remove the packages originally, but I figured they are obsolete (?). Anyway, will try this. Is there a way to install the 'unity 2d' again? Or will it be available when I install the ubuntu-desktop?

Comment: Worked like a charm! Never mind the question in the comment, unity-2d was already installed. It seams if you remove ubuntu-desktop (like I did by accident) it causes it to not detect unity-2d... I didn't see this error anywhere else so I might post a screenshot of it later. Thanks again!