# 14.04 won't update

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates

I haven't used this system for a while, so when I went to update it I started getting error messages such as this:

```
E:Line 1 too long in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list.
E:The list of sources could not be read.
E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I'm way out of my depth here, please help.

Edit: The result of `head -n 1 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list`

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en data-adblockkey=MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBANnylWw2vLY4hUn9w06zQKbhKBfvjFUCsdFlb6TdQhxb9RXWXuI4t31c+o8fYOv/s8q1LGPga3DE1L/tHU4LENMCAwEAAQ==_MaYS1KVPt2+/yDcH97o943cwuSBXaOPOGTouhf+8hyKGWccg8Zq9mVqKE6OV/PIsUTzrudXE+o5hzXbLvX+2HA==><head><meta charset=utf-8><title>medibuntu.org&nbsp;-&nbspThis website is for sale!&nbsp;-&nbspmedibuntu Resources and Information.</title><noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/trusty.list/?gtnjs=1"></noscript><meta name=GOOGLEBOT content="index, follow, all"><meta name=robots content="index, follow, all"><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0"><meta name=description content=This website is for sale! medibuntu.org is your first and best source for all of the information you’re looking for. From general topics to more of what you would expect to find here, medibuntu.org has it all. We hope you find what you are searching for!><link href="data:image/png;base64,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" type=image/png rel="shortcut icon"><script src=http://img.sedoparking.com/js/jquery-1.11.3.custom.min.js></script><!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
```

so I guess that's a problem!!

Comment: Hassle free! 
1 - Backup your data. 
2 - Install a fresh new copy.

Comment: A reinstall may not be necessary, could you edit your question to include the output of `head -n 1 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list` please

Comment: Medibuntu  stopped a while back. There may be a solution on https://askubuntu.com/questions/223179/how-to-remove-medibuntu-repository-and-packages

Comment: Line 1 too long in source list. Remove Line 1 and try again

Comment: Thanks for the answers, my system is now updated and working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/sources.list/#Ubuntu-14-04 shows the default sources.list, maybe you can backup yours and give it a try with the default settings. 
You could also use https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ which lets you generate your sources.list plus add some repositories you whish to add. 
Also medibuntu is not supported any longer, as you may have some unresolved dependencies which will be replaced through regular supported packages if you purge medibuntu. You should enable ubuntu-restricted-addons and ubuntu-restricted-extras as well as install the vlc repository.
When using synaptic you can easily manually edit (disable, enable, or delete) your sources.list entries.

Answer (score 0):

Remove or backup your "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list" and update.