# Help with updating and receiving error message "Ignoring File"

Tags: updates

New here, but loving Ubuntu. I have this nagging issue hoping to get help resolving.

```
username@username:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for jovial: 
N: Ignoring file 'medibuntu.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
username@username:~$
```

Comment: AFAIK the [Medibuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medibuntu) project has been dead for several years: to clean up after it see [How to remove medibuntu repository and packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223179/how-to-remove-medibuntu-repository-and-packages)

Comment: Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu*` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list.save.1` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list.save` and I'll take a look for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` that it is complaining about and fix the errors it is complaining about.  You will have to use `sudo`.

If you edit your question to include a list of the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, and the source of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list`, more clear instructions can be given.

It would also help if you edit your question and explain what you did right before this started happening. It appears that you have web page code in your `medibuntu.list`.